# Copy a range of data from one worksheet & paste 18 times in the other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Helloo,

I need Copy a range of data from one worksheet & paste 18 times of each data in the other worksheet.

Eg.,
I need to copy the data starting from Row 6 Column A,F,G from one sheet named "Inputs"
And need to paste the data 18 times starting from Row 6 of Column A,C,D in other sheet named "locale_Data"

So, the first data of input sheet should be pasted into Row (6:23) of sheet "locale_Data" & follows the other data in a sequential manner.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show us your code and its issues to let you help you with

Answer (score 1):

If you have values in range say A6:A10 of Inputs worksheet and you would like to copy them in locale_Data worksheet 18 times starting at Row 6 you can do something like this.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, startAt, totalRowsToCopy  As Integer
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet

Set sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs")
Set sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("locale_Data")
LastRow = sheet1.Cells(sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

sheet1.Range("A6:A" & (LastRow)).Copy
startAt = 6
totalRowsToCopy = LastRow - startAt + 1
For i = 1 To 18
  sheet2.Range("A" & startAt & ":A" & (startAt + totalRowsToCopy - 1)).PasteSpecial
  startAt = startAt + totalRowsToCopy
Next i
```

(Edited after [Mat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug) suggestion)

If you just want to copy value in Row 6 18 times in another worksheet you  can do something like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs").Range("A6").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("locale_Data").Range("A6:A23").PasteSpecial
```

You have to repeat this code for each cells.

And if you want to change 18 to some other number you can always concatenate cell range like

```
Range("A6:A" & (6 + 18)).PasteSpecial
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because of the number of SO questions that wouldn't need to be asked if only people stopped writing code that relies on `.Select` and `Selection` (and `.Activate`), and implicitly work against the `ActiveSheet`. You could simply do `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inputs").Range("A6").Copy` instead, for example.

Comment: Thanks Mat's Mug.I agree with you and 'll do that from next time.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your answer, downvotes aren't immutable ;-)

Comment: :) Did.It is always good to meet people like you specially when trying to start participating in new community.

Comment: Hi, Thanks much for your answer! But this works only for first row data. I need to copy all the existing data present in Input sheet and paste it sequentially in locale_Data Sheet.. 

Please can you help ?

Comment: If you have multiple item in Column A and want to copy them all 18 times in sequentially you can do something like the one I posted in my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this. Ihave shown for only one column. you can repeat for other columns. Make sure to change the range `$A$1:$A$2` to your desired data range.

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

```
D1 = INDEX($A$1:$A$2,QUOTIENT(ROW()-ROW($D$1),18)+1)
```